# Set up .db file as odbc data source

Tags: database, excel, odbc

I have a very simple .db file with 6 tables in it. For the purpose of a demonstration i would like to set up this file as an odbc data source so that i explain the concept of linking tables and return some data to an excel spreadsheet.

Does anyone know how to set up a .db file as an odbc data source?

Thank you,
Tommy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on a 64bit Windows and the .db file was made with Access: go to %windir%\syswow64 and find an executable called odbcad32.exe. Run it and it'll take you to the 32bit version of the ODBC control panel. Under the User DSN tab (or System DSN if you have access) click Add and choose Microsoft Access Paradox Driver (*.db), this'll open a dialog for you to fill in with the name and filepath.

Once that's complete, you're done; just access it like any other ODBC data source.

edit: for 32bit windows just go to Control panel > administrative tools > ODBC datasources (don't have one handy to test this so this may be wildly innacurate)

Comment: If the .db file came from somewhere else, you'll need to find an appropriate ODBC driver of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i should have been more specific with my question because the file was from SQLite. I have since worked out how to solve this (by getting the SQLite odbc driver)